# the tab key keeps focusing inside the Iframe tag

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, rxjs, tabindex

I have an iframe inside my angular project, when the user clicks on the tab key inside the iframe, it loops twice, I mean it focuses on the all items inside the iframe and doesn't go outside the Iframe till the second loop ends

```
      <iframe
        [id]="trackById"
        [class.active]="!this.hasActivePip"
        [src]="sanitizedUrl"
        style="border: 0;"
        webkitallowfullscreen
        allowfullscreen
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        [title]="title"
      ></iframe>
```

I need the focus to go outside the iframe after visiting all elements inside it, it goes back to the first element after focusing on the last one in the iframe